# Record of discriminated union

Tags: typescript

Taken this structured messages:

```
type MessageVariant<T extends string, P = {}> = {
  type: T;
  payload: P;
};

type BoundsChangedMessage = MessageVariant<
  "bounds_changed",
  {
    bounds: number[][];
  }
>;

type ChangeLayoutMessage = MessageVariant<
  "change_layout",
  {
    name: string;
  }
>;

type Message = BoundsChangedMessage | ChangeLayoutMessage;
```

I want to be able to express a strong record of:

```
const handlers: MessageHandler = {
  bounds_changed: (message/*: BoundsChangedMessage*/) => {},
  change_layout: (message/*: ChangeLayoutMessage*/) => {},
};
```

So far I have been trying various attempts without luck, including:

```
type MessageHandler = {
  [T in Message["type"]]: (message: MessageVariant<T, /* Payload? */>) => void;
}
```

Here is a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCA1JAnAlkgdsADwAqUEAHsBPgCbxTzC74oA0UAClALxQDeAXwB8vAQFgAUFCihIALigkA3FJlgkIADYB7JLUWdVkwcalzoAIR0BXOvADCACwJpacRKmh8PyNJlwCYjUoACIAI1t7AH0AYxdWCFpQthD%20EJlIu3pFfBsAW3CILABtAF1y4xlBKWEzSQsoZ1cIABlNW2BfLzFu-2w8QiIQ0PiW6K0Om2AUtIyofCR8iEUmFhQqqBrJOqlzcGg%207yhrbMcEtyOoAB8mi7aproQ-CHr9yFhnrwAJAlotYpidLSKAlMg4fCfTxoEqhCyhMplRQACmW0JWUJeAUGxBIHAA9AAqLiaXT6AD8UEJ%20OEAEpeKIAG46HC0YzbKSxHT4JhQBL-YrwRRHX50AFYIEhLIxMaJAxQVFfNBExSnezNOVHan0niiISpEGytATR4otEvFV3FrtECdLX4nV6wQG0x7SRSIA) for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Key mapping via "as"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) and change your `MessageHandler` type definition to the following

```js
type Message = BoundsChangedMessage | ChangeLayoutMessage;

type MessageHandler = {
  [M in Message as M["type"]]: (message: M) => void;
}
```

Here is the link to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCA1JAnAlkgdsADwAqUEAHsBPgCbxTzC74oA0UACuVTfVACUIAYwD2WWkSYt2UAK74A1vlEB3fAD4oAXigBvAL5bdegLAAoKFFCQAXFBIBuC1bBIQAG1FJa9zs-MDAIsbaAAhUQV6AGEACwI0WjhEVGhdZOQ0TFwCYgAiACNIungAfWF41ghaPI49KCKo+Ht8OQBbAogsAG0AXT6oIwDQqDiEiAAZd0jgDNSdWARMjGw8QiI8ivHSj2m5YFr9KHwkNoh7aRxWQY1g8xG5tAZdCKaxqqSl+YAfUcq0KYgGaPCB3B5fNAACQItA8XQWZksUG6MCgV0WKSeUCQDBg3TyoTyvV69gAFGdMedYABKHRaABuohwtACBhcFjE+CYUEqsK6zQxy2hdDhWARLgaxXo5X+1TJFOWtO0WnqnPgojhADovChyRCIJrQhwFalNW5PN5aNTHIM2BKtlUdntgPL9UqVVA1RqDTq9ZTDeAIMb9Wb3F4fNbBhYghYgA) with the full example

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that record type by defining the message handler type like below.

```js
type Message = BoundsChangedMessage | ChangeLayoutMessage;

type MessageHandler = {
  [K in Message as K['type']]: (message: K) => void;
}

const handlers: MessageHandler = {
  bounds_changed: m => {
    console.log(m);
  },
  change_layout: m => {
    console.log(m)
  }
}
```