# How to make Typescript infer a generic method argument type in an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I make this work?

```
const variant1 = (data: { hello: number }) => {/* Do some work here... */};

const variant2 = (data: { hi: string }) => {/* Do some work here... */};

interface Data<T = unknown> {
  callback: (data: T) => void;
}

const f: Record<string, Data> = {
  name1: variant1, // '(data: {hello: number}) => void' is not assignable to type 'Data<unknown>'
  name2: variant2, // '(data: {hi: string}) => void' is not assignable to type 'Data<unknown>'
}

/* 
  What I want:

  const f: Record<string, Data> = {
    name1: variant1, // (data: { hello: number }) => void
    name2: variant2, // (data: { hi: string }) => void
  }
 */
```

In other words, I want Typescript to insert an actual type of a method argument instead of the generic.

Can we make it without removing an explicit type from the `f`?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EsFigRhgXhgCgBMEoEAuGAbxgAsBTAGwZArAFcBbAIzqRgF8AlLgB8VAPQAqGABEQMCCA50YAdxBIA1rV50AdAZiTx-ANwAoc6EixEqdFABMuAsVIVqNFBWiowAcwFhHDFKKVl5RWU1DW16JH1DYzNLFAxeADMEYBUZEgQAHgAVFzYwTTAQVTBQ8xh6mGAEJi5szQoifIoi4LE4EBRCC35La2gYDIoAJTpQJEIC3zT-ABpZfLE8SjqGsARlTAo7NAxMNfFxGAByTvcqeiYWGHZuXiFReAHCK5gUCGeQLAEBAICh-HsuAwVFB5FAAJ4ABxUVzypAKZQqVRqVx29T2ykcR2QJyc50uNzc5Hu3gUUD8-neIU%20gx%20fwBQJBYIhUJgMN5iORqMKGMq1REOJG5nCuJgAHUaCQYABJNQOMiWBqNcDjSYwGZzBZLAJrIWbKgyzX4uiHeDEhxnGAXVxdKg6R6sTg8PiMvpfC27fZ0Qm2%20wYRxk513TyMZg%20OnLIIffqDGUjIziIA)

Comment: Remove the explicit typing `: Record<string, Data>` and it will be inferred properly

Comment: I need the type to be specified explicitly. In reality, the `Data` interface contains a lot more fields.

Comment: Could you explain what's the point of generics here? Also `Data` definition doesn't match any of variant1/variant2 (`callback` property)

Comment: Maybe there isn't point here. It was an attempt to make it work. 

If there weren't the restriction about explicit type, it would be easy of course.

Comment: With explicit typing this cannot be possible, because this explicitly replaces any typing that was present before. Either drop this requirement, or deal with incorrect typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the type definition from the `f` variable, and TypeScript will resolve the types automatically

```js
const variant1 = (data: { hello: number }) => {/* Do some work here... */};

const variant2 = (data: { hi: string }) => {/* Do some work here... */};

const f = {
  name1: variant1,
  name2: variant2,
}

f.name1({ hello: 1 });
f.name2({ hi: "" });
```

Here is the link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EsFigRhgXhgCgBMEoEAuGAbxgAsBTAGwZArAFcBbAIzqRgF8AlLgB8VAPQAqGABEQMCCA50YAdxBIA1rV50AdAZiTx-ANwAoc6EixEqdFABMuAsVIVqNFBWiowAcwFhHDFKKVl5RWU1DW16JH1DYzNLa2gYADMXSnMYPJgwBGVMCjs0DEwAGlz8wuVHUuRyp2r%20Swy9OrpMfE9GZgpsIQsOrsde2m8YACJpoIsgA)

Comment: Yeah, it will work, but can we get the same result with an explicit type? I have this restriction.

Comment: Does the `Data` interface contain any unique fields like `type`, `category`, or smth? If yes - you can refer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72590947/record-of-discriminated-union